# How to echo user after login

Tags: codeigniter, authentication, user-controls, echo, textfield

**strong text** i want to echo user who created data but seems it is possible?somebody know this issue?

> This is my controller

class Auth extends CI_Controller {

```
public function index(){
    $data['users'] = $this->User_model->get();
    $this->load->view('login_page');
}

public function login(){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $data = $this->User_model->login ($email, $password);

    if($data){
        $this->session->set_userdata('user', $data);
        redirect('Users');
    }
    else{
        header('location:'.base_url().$this->index());
        Echo 'error';
    } 
}
```

}

> This is my model

class User_model extends CI_Model {

```
private $_table = "users";


public function get( $id = false )
{

    if ($id) {
        $this->db->where('id =', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get($this->_table);
        return $query->row_array();
    }

    $query = $this->db->get($this->_table);    
    return $query->result_array();
}

public function insert($data)
{ 
    $data['password'] = password_hash($data['password'],PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $this->db->insert($this->_table, $data);

}

public function update($data)
{
    $id = $data['id'];
    unset($data['id']);
    $data['password'] = password_hash($data['password'],PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $this->db->where('id =', $id);
    $this->db->update($this->_table, $data);
}

public function delete($id)
{
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->delete($this->_table);
}

public function login($email, $password){
    $query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('email'=>$email, $data['password'] = password_hash($data['password'],PASSWORD_DEFAULT))) ;

    return $query->row_array();
}
```

}

> This is my view Where i want to echo the user in created by textbox below. Anyone have an idea?

<

```
!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Roles</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Roles</h1>
       <div class="container">


       <form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('roles/add')?>" >


          <label>Code</label>
          <input type="text"  name="code" placeholder="Code">


          <label>Description</label>
          <input type="text" name="description" placeholder="Description">

        <label>Permissions</label>
        <input type="text" name="permissions" placeholder="Permissions">

              <!--  created By -->
          <label>Created by</label>
          <input type="text"  name="created_by" placeholder="Name">

        <button type="submit"  value="save" >Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is this "$data = $this->User_model->login password_verify($email, $password);"

Comment: Tell us more details about this. Your full question is contain of bunch of codes

Comment: sorry i forgot to remove >login password_verify

Comment: i cant login because the password hashed but i try to login where the user not hashed then i can login.

Comment: What is this `public function login($email, password_verify $password){` look like a syntax error

Comment: yes i forget to remove password_verify im just trying if it works .. but if i remove that password verify then it works but it wont work if password hashed

Comment: You have to hash ALL the password or NONE of the password/

Comment: i already hashed the password. but it wont work .

Comment: ok got it :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller use method like :

```
$data = $this->User_model->login($email, $password);
```

Now in Modal :

```
public function login($email,$password){
 $password = password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('email'=>$email, 'password'=>$password));

        return $query->row_array();
    }
```

Hope it may help :)

Comment: this won't work - `password_hash` generates different hashes for the same password

Answer (score 0):

try the following

your model

```
public function login($email,$password){

    $query = $this->db
        ->from('users')
        ->where('email', $email)
        ->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() !== 1)   throw new Exception('Invalid User');

    $arrUser = $query->row_array();

    if (!password_verify($password, $arrUser['password']))  throw new Exception('Invalid Password');

    return $arrUser;
}
```

and your controller

```
public function login(){

    try

    {
        //load session library
        $this->load->library('session');

        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $this->session->set_userdata('user', $this->User_model->login password_verify($email, $password));
        redirect('Users');

    }
    catch(\Throwable $e)
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', $e->getMessage());
        header('location:'.base_url('user'));
    }
}
```